# Python : cannot call static method on run-time retrieved type

Tags: python, reflection, static

I have a base class:

```
class MyBaseClass:
    @abstractmethod
    def from_list(list_float: List[float]) -> Self:
        pass

    @staticmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def fn() -> int: 
        pass
```

All children of that class implement `from_list` and static `fn`, since they are abstract.

Now, I have another class 'MyOptions' :

```
class MyOptions:
    @abstractclass
    def related_to_type(): type(MyBaseClass)
```

All `MyOptions` children implement `related_to_type`, which returns a type that is a child of `MyBaseClass`. What I want is:

Provided a `MyOptions` child (which is unknown until runtime), call `fn` on its related type, returned by `related_to_type()`. In other term, I want:

```
options: MyOptions = MyOptionChild()
type_opt = options.related_to_type() # this should return a MyBaseClass child type 
result = type_opt.fn() # error here
```

The error is that `type_opt` contains an variable of type `<class 'abc.ABCMeta'>`, on which I cannot call my static function `fn`.
PS : I cannot make MyOptions generic with a type argument because the related type is known at run-time only

What can I do to call a static function on a variable containing a "reflected class" in Python ?
Typically, in java, you would do:

```
Method method = myBaseClassChild.getMethod("fn");
int result = method.invoke(null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MyOptionChild` needs to return a concrete type that implements `fn`; it's not clear from your pseudocode whether you did this in your actual code, but it should "just work".

You can use `Generic` to type-annotate it in such a way that a function can take an arbitrary `MyOptions` and do reasonable things with its associated `MyBaseClass`, and a type-checker can validate that the appropriate interfaces are being used.

Here's a working example:

```
from abc import abstractmethod
from typing import Generic, Type, TypeVar

class MyBaseClass:
    @staticmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def fn() -> int:
        pass

_MyBaseClass = TypeVar("_MyBaseClass", bound=MyBaseClass)

class MyOptions(Generic[_MyBaseClass]):
    @abstractmethod
    def related_to_type(self) -> Type[_MyBaseClass]:
        pass

def call_fn(options: MyOptions) -> int:
    return options.related_to_type().fn()

# Everything before this line deals with abstract types.
# Now the concrete implementations:

class MyChildClass(MyBaseClass):
    @staticmethod
    def fn() -> int:
        return 42

class MyOptionChild(MyOptions[MyChildClass]):
    def related_to_type(self) -> Type[MyChildClass]:
        return MyChildClass

# Now call_fn with our concrete MyOptionChild:
print(call_fn(MyOptionChild()))  # 42
```

Comment: Thank you, this works :) Actually I didn't even need Generic for that, if I return Type[MyBaseClass], I can call the static function on it from the child type returned :)

Comment: Yes, the generic is useful if you want to be able to *statically* get the type of the more specific subclass out of its related options class (i.e. be able to access the `MyChildClass` interface via a `MyOptionChild` and have mypy understand that's a safe thing to do).  At runtime it's the more specific type either way, as long as you don't do something silly like `return MyBaseClass` in the options class.